# Weird SourceTree commit bug

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Source Tree, and I ran into extremely weird bug:

I have a problem with a "ghost" unstaged file to commit, that just wont go away:

When I try to commit it it does nothing, it wont even move into staged files.

It shows even right after downloading into a brand new repo from remote where the bug is not present.

I tried clearing all cache with Ccleaner, did not help. I also just deleted the file, which fixed the issue, then I returned the file back (without any changes), and the ghost commit returned...

It's super annoying, as it wont let me leave any branch I create, keeps on telling me I have uncommited changes even though I do not.

The change that keeps on poping up is very simple thing that was already implemented into remote. I would provide any more detail or info but not sure what to post. This is how it looks like, ALWAYS after a fresh branch is created:
[image]
Any idea how do I make this thing go away? It drives me crazy, thanks

EDIT:
Found the main problem, I had the same file twice on main remote, one capitalized the other one not: https://prnt.sc/pe6nwz Damn...

Comment: More details? Screenshot? Git logs?

Comment: @CaiusJard Not sure what details to post, except a picture of how it looks like. There is nothing useful in  logs, it just stayed like this after that change was made, commited and merged a while back.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file in the main branch that you branch off for features, committing the delete, then re committing a new file add, same name, perhaps some white space differences to the old file?

Comment: What do you see in the console/terminal if you do a `git add -A` followed by `git commit -m "go away!"`. Possibly also with a `git status` before and in between?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for advices. What was wrong was the same file was 2 times on main remote, one with capizalized first letter the other one not. But it was not an easy fix, in  local repo there always was only one file showing, and in the ST commit was showing for the other one. When I corrected the name in my repo, the commit just switched to the other file... But we finally fixed it for good...

Comment: Good call, one to remember!